# Nginx - Disable http support

Tags: nginx, http

I want my server to only respond to https requests and my SSL configuration is working fine. My question is about how best to disable http...

Is it better to have a default server block that listens to port 80 and returns a 444 (see below), or to just **remove all port 80 server blocks altogether**? I would assume that the latter is better because it would result in the server doing the minimum amount of processing, but I can't find anything about this online, so perhaps I'm missing something?

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  return 444;
}
```

Comment: No listener can result in a timeout for anyone who makes a request. Returning a status code from the default server is a pretty good way to have clients fail fast. I would probably do the 444.

Comment: Thanks, Tim! When I hit it with curl, I get a "Connection refused" error. Is that the same as timeout? Also, in my particular scenario, I don't really care about clients that aren't using SSL. Does failing fast benefit the server in any way? I want to only optimize for the server.

Comment: Returning a status code probably takes very little processing. Not listening on the port takes even less. If that's all you care about then just don't have anything listening on port 80.

Comment: Even better could be to drop the traffic to port 80 in your firewall.

Comment: Thanks, all. I'm going to comment out the server blocks completely and see how that goes.